# mysqld high cpu wakeups

Tags: mysql, cpu-usage

Using Ubuntu 14.0.4, Apache 2.4.7, MySQL 5.5.41.
mysqld has constant CPU wakeups between 15 and 25 per second, and thus accounts for more than 50% of cpu wakeups.
Only one utilization of MySQL: Pyd.io, and only used personally, thus almost no connections.

Any idea how to reduce this?
Thanks!

Comment: Queries per second avg: 0.002.